# promise.all return only first data

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

am iterating over a number of function using the bluebird promise.all api, but i seem to only get the data return from the first function

```
var _ = require('lodash');
var x = require('x-ray')();
var sentiment = require('sentiment');
var Promise = require('bluebird');
```

and the code below

```
 function joyPolitics() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        x('http://www.myjoyonline.com/politics.php', 'ul.opinion-listings li', [{
            title: '.head .title a',
            desc: '.info',
            date: '.head',
            img: 'div.image-inner > a img@src',
            url: '.head .title a@href',
            fullStory: x('.head .title a@href', ['.main-article-section .storypane p'])
        }])(function(err, obj) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err)
            } else {
                _(obj).forEach(function(story) {
                    var a = story.fullStory;
                    story.category = 'politics';
                    story.mood = sentiment(a.join()).score;
                });
                resolve(obj);
            }
        })
    })
}
function joyEnt() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        x('http://www.myjoyonline.com/entertainment.php', 'ul.opinion-listings li'
     ...
}
function execute() {
    return Promise.all(joyEnt(),joyPolitics());

}
```

when the call the execute on the data above

```
activateCtrl.execute()
        .then(function(data,data1) {
            // return activateCtrl.loadToParse(data);
            res.json([data,data1]);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            res.send(err);
        })
```

it return data, but data1 is null

Comment: What does `x` do. Is it possible that there are no `ul.opinion-listings li` on the `entertainment.php` page?

Comment: edited to include the external library

Comment: Assuming you're actually `resolve`-ing in `joyEnt` all the resolved data is going to be in an array in the first argument `data`. See the first comment here: http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html

Comment: it appear i cant use return with promise.all , about to try this without return , and about the data in one array, when i call data[0] it return only one item from the first function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> … Promise.all(joyEnt(),joyPolitics()); …
> ```

[`Promise.all`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.all.html) takes an array, not multiple arguments:

```
Promise.all([joyEnt(),joyPolitics()]);
```

Also its result promise will not fulfill with multiple values, but with a single array, so you'll need to adjust your `then` callback to that - or use [`spread`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html) instead. You also might want to consider using [`Promise.join`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.join.html).